# How to copy one NSMutableArray to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an nsmutablearray(xmlParseArray) having values firstname and id, I want to copy only firstname into another nsmutablearray(copyArray).

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you ever looked at the documentation for NSArray/NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean that the first array, `xmlParseArray`, contains a list of `NSDictionary` objects which each have objects attached to the keys "firstname" and "id". One way to accomplish that would be like this:

```
NSMutableArray *copyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[xmlParseArray count]];
for(NSDictionary *dict in xmlParseArray)
    if([dict objectForKey:@"firstname"])
        [copyArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"firstname"]];

// ...do whatever with copyArray...
[copyArray release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumption:  your `xmlParseArray` contains number of objects all of which have a `firstname` property and and an id property

```
NSMutableArray* nameArray = [[xmlParseArray valueForKey: @"firstname"] mutableCopy];

// nameArray is an array you own.
```

[-valueForKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ) when sent to an array causes the message `-valueForKey:` to be sent to each of its elements and a new array to be constructed from the return values.  The `-mutableCopy` ensures that the result is then turned into a mutable array as per your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[copyArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

or

```
[arr addObject:[copyArray objectAtIndex:0]];
  [arr addObject:[copyArray objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [oldArray mutableCopy];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:oldArray];
```

be aware that the objects in the array aren't copied, just the array itself (references to objects are maintained).

Comment: have you read the question? obviously the array contains dictionaries and he wants a copy of those in the new array without the id key.

Comment: I did later on read it again and saw that my answer was next to useless, but I couldn't bother to change it since the guy who actually asked the question duplicated it anyway. Plus it was almost unreadable. If you don't like it you can always down-vote. Plus, if you read the title, my answer is dead on ;-)